# Initial output of parent is lost while redirecting

Tags: c, bash, process, output-redirect

The program I was trying to write was supposed to define some constants (C macro/constants). So I wrote two C programs:

1. `hashgen` : This generates constants from the input file.
2. `loopy`  : This executes the `hashgen` with some file names.

Here is how I execute `loopy`:

`./loopy *.txt >> constants.h`

The loopy code snippet is below

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    char buf[256];
    puts("#ifndef CONSTS_DEFINED\n#define CONSTS_DEFINED");
    while(--argc > 0) {
         sprintf(buf, "./hashgen %s", argv[argc]);
         system(buf);
    }
    puts("#endif");
    return 0;
}
```

After executing the above script, the `#ifndef ....` lines are missing while `#endif` line is present. Why the children are overwriting the parent's output?

I agree that there are better ways to this, but there was a need for this at that moment. Now I want to know why this is happening. :)

Comment: I can't confirm this behaviour, I created a dummy `hashgen` script (`echo $@`) that outputs the same as the arguments and I can see everything. Btw there is a semicolon missing at the last `puts`.

Comment: Is the above really the code you run? There is a semicolon missing after the last puts.

Comment: Perhaps you can shows us also the code of `hashgen`

Comment: Guys the question is about behavior of code. I didn't paste the file as it was quite big. The actual programs are working. The output on screen verifies the correct behavior of the both programs. We are missing something related to how bash handles this redirection

Comment: So you say that without the redirection you see all the lines? Only when doing the append redirection `>>` they do not appear? I tested both and both cases behave the same.

Comment: @Pablo Exactly. After redirecting to file the overwriting is happening. I am analyzing the `strace` now. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The output from puts doesn't go directly to the file, but to an internal buffer. So when the external program is called, nothing has yet been output. The program outputs its things, and then the main program continues, and when it finishes, its stdio buffer is flushed, and your directives end up at the end. This appears with ordinary redirection too, not only appending.

A solution is to use fflush(stdout) before calling external programs which do I/O.

Comment: Ooops! Thank you very much. There were a lot of constants and I couldn't see the line at the end.